# Функция для определения окончания слова по числительному (1 год, 2 года, 5 лет)

Tags: php

Думаю, что вопрос актуальный. Во всех популярных сервисах данная фича есть. Порылся в нете. Накатал небольшую функцию, но че-то подумал, может кто-нибудь на хэшкоде скажет как будет сделать лучше?:) Хочется конечно, чтобы код работал быстро и со всеми числами (будь то миллион, миллиард, трилион и т.д. :) )

Вот, мой вариант:

```
function getInclinationByNumber($number, $arr = Array()) {
    $number = (string) $number;
    $numberEnd = substr($number, -2);
    $numberEnd2 = 0;
    if(strlen($numberEnd) == 2){
        $numberEnd2 = $numberEnd[0];
        $numberEnd = $numberEnd[1];
    }

    if ($numberEnd2 == 1) return $arr[2];
    else if ($numberEnd == 1) return $arr[0];
    else if ($numberEnd > 1 && $numberEnd < 5)return $arr[1];
    else return $arr[2];
}
echo getInclinationByNumber(10,Array('тетрадь', 'тетради', 'тетрадей')).'<br>';
```

Если что, поправляйте)) Русский учил плохо, а стиль программирования, как вы уже поняли, оставляет желать лучшего))

Comment: Повтор вопроса  
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215279/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php
Там кстати можно найти мою попытку упростить читабельность большого текста в котором надо склонить слова при помощи шаблонов.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ололо.

```
function number($n, $titles) {
  $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
  return $titles[($n % 100 > 4 && $n % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($n % 10, 5)]];
}
echo number(631, array('яблоко', 'яблока', 'яблок'));
```

Comment: вот к таким табличным вещам всегда надо стремиться.

Comment: распечатаю и повешу в рамочку, пять строчек

Answer (score 10):

Я пользуюсь такой

```
function num2word($num, $words)
{
    $num = $num % 100;
    if ($num > 19) {
        $num = $num % 10;
    }
    switch ($num) {
        case 1: {
            return($words[0]);
        }
        case 2: case 3: case 4: {
            return($words[1]);
        }
        default: {
            return($words[2]);
        }
    }
}

echo num2word(50, array('год', 'года', 'лет'));
```

Тоже, что и у KiTE , но немного по-другому реализовано. =)
Насколько я помню, можно еще 4 параметр передать. Типа  год,года,лет,лет
т.к. некоторые цифры определяются как, например, 2 параметр, а в русском языке звучат как третий. Пару раз сталкивался.

Comment: Тоже хорошо! Еще меньше операций вычисления остатка от деления.

Comment: А вы не помните случайно, что это за числа такие?))

Comment: не числа, а скорее слова.
например более сложные числительные : года, годов или рублей. Точно не помню. 
но во время использования вы сами заметите, что некоторые не правильные и добавите аргумент

Comment: Просто если массив чем-то дополнять, придется же наверное алгоритм сам переделывать? Вы наверное имеете в виду родительный падеж? Без одного года, без трех рублей и т.д.? А я даже если честно об этом и не задумывался пока что... Мне просто надо написать: два года назад, 5 дней назад и т.д. Вообщем как на ютубе или вконтакте...

Comment: Не, ничего ненадо. Это встречается редко. А для ваших целей пойдет

Answer (score 5):

Для Delphi как-то писал:

```
function GetUnitCase(const AValue: Int64; const AUnit1, AUnit2, AUnit3: String): String;
begin
  if (Abs(AValue) mod 100) in [11..19] then
    Result := AUnit3
  else
    case Abs(AValue) mod 10 of
      1:    Result := AUnit1;
      2..4: Result := AUnit2;
      else
            Result := AUnit3;
    end;
end;
```

Работает через вычисление остатка от деления.

**UPD:** Вариант для PHP:

```
function getUnitCase( $value, $unit1, $unit2, $unit3 ){
    $value = abs( (int)$value );
    if( ($value % 100 >= 11) && ($value % 100 <= 19) ){
        return $unit3;
    }else{
        switch( $value % 10 ){
            case 1:
                return $unit1;
            case 2:case 3:case 4:
                return $unit2;
            default:
                return $unit3;
        }
    }
}
echo getUnitCase(33, 'рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей');
```

Comment: Красиво...

Comment: Я бы немного оптимизировал:

    function getUnitCase( $value, $unit1, $unit2, $unit3 ){
        $value = abs( $value % 100 );
        if (11 > $value || $value > 19) {
            switch( $value % 10 ) {
                case 1:                 return $unit1; 
                case 2: case 3: case 4: return $unit2; 
            }
        }
        return $unit3;
    }

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, даже не знаю... Вроде бы как бы одинаково все... Только в предыдущем варианте значение возвращается при одном делении с остатком в 9 случаях (от 11 до 19), а в Вашем всего в 2 (когда $value = 12 или 13).

Comment: >echo getUnitCase(32345433343, 'рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей'); 

**рублей** а не **рубля** ли должно быть?

Comment: > а в Вашем всего в 2 (когда $value = 12 или 13)

Не два, а четыре (от 11 до 14 включительно). Но это не принципиально, можно и от 11 до 19 проверять, конечно. Результат не изменится.

PS Но в принципе вы правы, в switch нет смысла при $value <= 19. Поправил.

Comment: @Shrek, "... 433 тысячи 343 рублЕЙ" ? :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov возьми и проверь код! выводит **рублей**

Ну скорее всего это связано с длиной числа. Но ведь числа бывают и больше чем *32345433343* может быть и *323454333432432342342343*

Comment: @Shrek,

    php > echo getUnitCase(32345433343, 'рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей');
    рубля

> Ну скорее всего это связано с длиной числа. 

Это связанно c [PHP. Integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). Т.ч. нужны большие числа, используйте 64х битную платформу.

Comment: @Shrek, для целых чисел превышающих размер в 32 бита, можно сделать обертку. Например:

    function getUnitCaseEx($value, $unit1, $unit2, $unit3){
        if( preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*|0$/', $value) ){
            return getUnitCase(
                (int)substr($value, strlen($value) - 2, 2),
                $unit1, $unit2, $unit3
            );
        }else{
            return $unit3;
        }
    }

Берем из `$value` два последних символа, конвертируем в число и применяем `getUnitCase()`

Comment: KiTE, идея хорошая... Мне понравилась...

Comment: @Dobby007, ситуация, в которой целое число может вылазить за пределы `int32` - это сферический конь в вакууме. А, в любом другом случае, обработка числовых типов строковыми функциями - моветон.

Answer (score 0):

Немного причесанный-прокомментированный ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/89511/240030

```php
    /**
     * Получить правильное склонение слова для числа (напр. '1 яблоко', '2 яблока', '5 яблок').
     *
     * @param int $n Число
     * @param array $wordDeclensions 3 варианта склонения слова
     * @return string
     */
    function getWordNumericEnding(int $n, array $wordDeclensions): string
    {
        //Случаи - какое склонение использовать, в зависимости от последней цифры числа
        // 0 - 3 склонение
        // 1 - 1 склонение
        // 2 - 2 склонение
        // 3 - 3 склонение
        // 4 - 2 склонение
        // От 5 до 9 - всегда 3 склонение
        $cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];

        return $wordDeclensions[
            ($n % 100 > 4 && $n % 100 < 20)
                ? 2                          //Для чисел, заканчивающихся от 05 до 19 - всегда 3 склонение
                : $cases[min($n % 10, 5)]    //Иначе - выбирается случай согласно последней цифре числа.
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
     * For the formation of endings of words.
     * echo $this->morph(count($this->comments), "комментарий", "комментария", "комментариев")
     *
     * @param int $value number.
     * @param string $word0 word in the singular.
     * @param string $word1 word in the plural (2, 3).
     * @param string $word2 word in the plural.
     * @param string $separator separator, default '&nbsp;'.
     * @return string formed words
     * @access private.
     */
    private function morph($value, $word0, $word1, $word2, $separator = '&nbsp;')
    {
        if (preg_match('/1\d$/', $value)) {
            return $value.$separator.$word2;
        } elseif (preg_match('/1$/', $value)) {
            return $value.$separator.$word0;
        } elseif (preg_match('/(2|3|4)$/', $value)) {
            return $value.$separator.$word1;
        } else {
            return $value.$separator.$word2;
        }
    }
```