# Склонения слов на PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

Есть такая небольшая статистика

"N" Человек просят сейчас помощь!

```
if (n == 1) => "1 человек просит сейчас помощь"  
elseif ($n == 2) => "2 человекА просЯт сейчас помощь"
```

и так далее.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция для определения окончания слова по числительному (1 год, 2 года, 5 лет)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89458/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-1-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4-2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-5-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
function declOfNum($num, $titles) {
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

    return $num . " " . $titles[($num % 100 > 4 && $num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($num % 10, 5)]];
}

echo declOfNum(5, array('человек просит', 'человека просят', 'человек просят'));
```

Comment: Интересный алгоритм. Я раньше всегда использовал вариант примерно как у @klopp, а тут красиво и аккуратно.  
Единственное я делаю свертку примерно так:  

    sklonit("5:буханк(а,и,ок)")
Когда такие вызовы функций складываются с другими строками, то это выглядит естественнее.

Comment: Жаль нельзя плюсануть несколько раз) только вот при 11 значной цифре ошибочка Undefined offset

Comment: @Palmervan, есть кнопочка наградить, прямо под ответом.

Comment: @Palmervan @Mobyman да не суть. Раз вижу, что помог - и на душе хорошо ![http://sysedit.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/emoticon-00157-sun.gif][1]


  [1]: http://sysedit.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/emoticon-00157-sun.gif

Comment: @lampa это же сколько лет надо практиковать программирование что бы ум дошел до такого алгоритма :)

Answer (score 11):

Вот тут люди обновляют правила для разных языков: [Language Plural Rules](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html).

Для русского языка:

```
one   → n mod 10 is 1 and n mod 100 is not 11;
few   → n mod 10 in 2..4 and n mod 100 not in 12..14;
many  → n mod 10 is 0 or n mod 10 in 5..9 or n mod 100 in 11..14;
other → everything else
```

Таким образом:

```
function pluralCategory($count)
{
  $mod10  = $count % 10;
  $mod100 = $count % 100;

  if (is_int($count) && $mod10 == 1 && $mod100 != 11) {
    return 'one';
  } elseif (($mod10 > 1 && $mod10 < 5) && ($mod100 < 12 || $mod100 > 14)) {
    return 'few';
  } elseif ($mod10 == 0 || ($mod10 > 4 && $mod10 < 10) || ($mod100 > 10 && $mod100 < 15)) {
    return 'many';
  } else {
    return 'other';
  }
}
```

Само собой, в ответе будет только категория. Для слова "человек" массив соответствий будет таким:

```
one   → человек
few   → человека
many  → человек
other → человека
```

Демо:

```
$word = array(
  'one'   => 'человек',
  'few'   => 'человека',
  'many'  => 'человек',
  'other' => 'человека',
);

for ($i = 1; $i < 500; $i++) {
  echo $i.' '.$word[pluralCategory($i)].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: В русском языке хватит и трех склонений.

Comment: +1: систематизированные поязыковые таблицы — это круто!

Answer (score 8):

Вариант для данного случая избыточен, но он подходит и для других случаев, когда у слова не две, а три формы:

```
for( $n = 1; $n < 4096; $n++ )
{
    $plural = 
    (
        $n % 10 == 1 && $n % 100 != 11 
        ? 
        'человек'
        :
        (
            $n % 10 >= 2 && $n % 10 <= 4 && 
            (
                $n % 100 < 10 || $n % 100 >= 20 
            )
            ?
            'человека'
            :
            'человек'
        )
    );
    print "$n $plural\n";
}
```

Comment: Что-то меня цикл пугает))

Comment: Циклов пугаться - программы не писать :-)

Comment: @klopp ваш комментарий добавили в рандомайзер на мониторе одном в офисе :D (я про боязнь циклов) за коммент +

Comment: @klopp наоборот, циклов бояться - рефакторингом заниматься!)

Answer (score 7):

Отмечусь тоже. Скрестил алгоритм [[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa) со своими шаблонами. Мне кажется так удобнее. Кода на много строк из-за свободной записи регулярного выражения, поэтому просто дам ссылку на реализацию с тестами:
http://ideone.com/XQgK2g
В функцию sklonit надо просто передать текст содержащий сколько угодно шаблонов:

```
// шаблон 1
[число:начало(конец1,конец2,конец3)] // начало+конец
[2:яблок(о,а,)] // яблока
// шаблон 2
число[разделитель:начало(конец1,конец2,конец3)] // число+разделитель+начало+конец
2[ :яблок(о,а,)] // 2 яблока
```

При этом если во втором шаблоне разделитель это число, то считается, что это шаблон первого типа, то есть

```
1[2:яблок(о,а,)] // 1яблока , а не 12яблоко, если воспринимать это как шаблон 2
```

Comment: Клево! Такой вопрос, допустим нужно склонять сразу два слова по одному числу, не удобней было бы как-то объединить запись? Вроде: 

[2:человек(,а,) нивидимк(а,и,ок)]

Comment: Можно конечно усложнить шаблон, но и такой вариант не плох:  

2[ :человек(,а,)] [2:невидимк(а,и,ок)]

Answer (score 4):

А можно воспользоваться нормальной библиотекой - https://github.com/wapmorgan/Morphos (http://morphos.io) , которая сама поймёт как нужно склонять любое слово.

Вы просто пишете

```
morphos\Russian\pluralize(10, 'комментарий')
```

и получаете "10 комментариев"