# функция сколько прошло с момента публикации

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Добрый день!
Пишу функцию которая определяет время с момента публикации комментария, но есть загвоздка. у нашего времени в отличии от американского, где есть единичное и множественное чисор например year и years, у нас получается даже с секундами запарка, пример 1 секунду (назад) 2 секунды, 5 секунд, и так далее, или например 1 месяц, 2 месяца, 5 месяцев, или 1 год назад, 2 года, 5 лет, и т.п.

Сел я значит писать и вот как не кошерно это получается:

```
function timeAgo($time_ago) {
    $cur_time   = time();
    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
    $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
    $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
    $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
    $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
    $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
    $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );

    $msg = null;
    // Seconds
    if($seconds <= 60){
        if ($seconds == 1)
            $msg = "1 секунду";
        else if ( $seconds < 5 )
            $msg = "$seconds секунды";
        else if ( $seconds <= 20 )
            $msg = "$seconds секунд";
        else if ( $seconds == 21 )
            $msg = "21 секунду";
        else if ( $seconds <= 24 )
            $msg = "$seconds секунды";
        else if ( $seconds <= 29 )
            $msg = "$seconds секунд";
        else if ( $seconds == 30 )
            $msg = "30 секунд";
        ...
    }

...
    return msg;
}
```

В общем, дорогие прогеры, может есть готовое решение, или можно как-то упростить это дело, а то если так для всех случаев описывать очень долго, да и читабельность никакая...

Буду признателен за любые наводки по этой теме.

Comment: Вот вам таблица: http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215279/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php такой же вопрос конкретно для PHP, можете посмотреть непосредственно мой ответ, там задача решается через передачу функции шаблона

Comment: Конкретно в случае секунд шаблон будет такой: `[$second:секунд(а,ы,)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно правильно распределить 3 формы слов:

- всё, что оканчивается на 1 - "секунда"
- всё, что оканчивается на 2 - 4 - "секунды"
- всё остальное - "секунд"
- дополнительно - все числа от 5 до 20 - "секунд"

Вот универсальная функция на PHP:

```
function diff_time_string($start_date, $end_date = NULL, $words = NULL)
{
    //  Если конечная дата периода не указана, используется текущая дата и время
    if (!$end_date)
    {
        $end_date = time();
    }
    //  Unix-даты переводятся в текстовый формат
    if (is_numeric($start_date))
    {
        $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date);
    }
    if (is_numeric($end_date))
    {
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date);
    }

    //  Через аргумент можно передать массив слов на другом языке
    if (!$words)
    {
        $words = [
            'y' => ['год', 'года', 'лет'],
            'm' => ['месяц', 'месяца', 'месяцев'],
            'd' => ['день', 'дня', 'дней'],
            'h' => ['час', 'часа', 'часов'],
            'i' => ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут'],
            's' => ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд'],
        ];
    }

    //  Разница формируется в виде объекта класса DateInterval
    $interval = date_diff(date_create($start_date), date_create($end_date));
    if (is_object($interval))
    {
        $string = [];
        foreach ($words as $type => $variants)
        {
            //  Нулевые значения не добавляются, если только они не идут после ненулевых
            if ($interval->$type > 0 || count($string))
            {
                $number = $interval->$type;
                $word = $variants[2];
                if ($number < 5 || $number > 20)
                {
                    $number %= 10;
                    if ($number == 1)
                    {
                        $word = $variants[0];
                    }
                    elseif ($number >= 2 && $number <= 4)
                    {
                        $word = $variants[1];
                    }
                }

                $string[] = $interval->$type.' '.$word;
            }
        }

        return implode(' ', $string);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Использование

```
echo diff_time_string(646834565);
echo '<br>';
echo diff_time_string('2004-12-08 14:23:39');
echo '<br>';
echo diff_time_string('2016-01-30 18:45:11');
echo '<br>';
echo diff_time_string('2016-05-03 12:19:38');
```

Результат

```
25 лет 10 месяцев 2 дня 3 часа 59 минут 2 секунды
11 лет 4 месяца 25 дней 4 часа 51 минута 28 секунд
3 месяца 3 дня 0 часов 29 минут 56 секунд
6 часов 55 минут 29 секунд
```

Comment: отличное решение :)

Comment: А как можно использовать interval format тут, чтобы отформатировать вывод, например если разница меньше часа, показывает только секунды, если пошли часы, то показывает сколько часов и минут, если пошли дни то уже только дни, если месяца только они, ну и годы только годы... ?

Comment: ещё не могу найти такой член у dateinterval класса $interval->$type может надо как-то по нему смотреть?

Comment: В $interval->$type вместо $type поочерёдно подставляются ключи массива $words, то есть я проверяю свойства $interval->y, $interval->m и т.д.
Для форматирования добавьте после $string[] = $interval->$type.' '.$word; такое условие:

if (count($string) == 2 || $type != 'h')
{
 break;
}

Comment: Благодарю, очень элегантное решение получилось!

Answer (score 2):

На С можно создать массив указателей на строки и возвращать указатель на строку.

```
char sec_0[] = "секунд";
char sec_1[] = "секунда";
char sec_2[] = "секунду";
......

char * str_sec[60] = {sec_0,sec_2, .....} ;

char * get_str_sec(int sec)
{
   return str_sec[sec];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Берем остаток от деления на 10 (для больших чисел) или саму цифру (если это от 0 до 9) и сравниваем по правилу:

- 0, 5-9 - `д`
- 1 - `ду`; (21, 31, 41 работает то же правило)
- от 2 до 4 - `ды`, (от 22 до 24 и так далее)

С минутами и часами такое же правило, только окончания другие.

---

Не идеально, но как сырой демо пример на php:

```
$time = ['zeroOrMany' => ['sec' => 'секунд',
                          'min' => 'минут',
                          'hour' => 'часоов'
                         ],
        'one' =>        ['sec' => 'секунду',
                          'min' => 'минуту',
                          'hour' => 'час'
                         ],
         'few' =>       ['sec' => 'секунды',
                          'min' => 'минуты',
                          'hour' => 'часов'
                         ],
        ];

function getSuffix($num, $type) {
    global $time;

    if ($num > 9) {
        $num = $num % 10;
    }

    if ($num == 0 || in_array($num, [5,6,7,8,9])) {
        return $time['zeroOrMany'][$type];
    } else if ($num == 1) {
        return $time['one'][$type];
    } else if (in_array($num, [2,3,4])) {
        return $time['few'][$type];
    }   
}

$num = 666;
echo $num.' '.getSuffix($num, 'min');
```

https://ideone.com/ikAedV

`global` тут лишь для примера... не следует использовать глобальные переменные