# Как добавить к числам (21,22,23,24) слово "рублей" в нужном падеже?(Java)

Tags: java, операторы, switch

Есть решение, но оно неправильно работает с числами 21,22,23,24 и тому подобными..как нужно дополнить этот код?

```
public class Task5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int money = 21;

    switch (money) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println(money + " рубль");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println(money + " рубля");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(money + " рубля");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println(money + " рубля");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println(money + " рублей");
        break;



    }
}
```

Comment: @Akina [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/178779)

Comment: Дмитрий. Если вам интересна судьба вашего вопроса - попробуйте переформулировать его так, чтобы в нем хотя бы вопросительный знак был. Сейчас он очень похож на требование, от того и собирает минусы.

Answer (score 4):

Все куда проще. Смотрим по предпоследней цифре: если 1 - рублей иначе по последней цифре: 1 - рубль, 2-4 рубля, остальное - рублей.

[Тестить тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K4LmHx).

```
public string GetRubleAddition(int num)
{
    var preLastDigit = num % 100 / 10;
    if (preLastDigit == 1) 
    {
        return "рублей";
    }

    switch (num % 10)
    {
        case 1:
            return "рубль";
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return "рубля";
        default:
            return "рублей";
    }
}
```

Comment: 21 рублей? 32 рублей?

Comment: @Denis согласен, обновился.

Comment: Одиннадцать рубль - или все-таки рублей?

Comment: @PavelMayorov действительно, обновился

Answer (score -1):

Преобразовать число в строку и проанализировать последний символ, а также предпоследний, если длина строки больше 1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string itos(long long number);
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::string Number = itos(3214);
    std::string Text;
    switch(Number[Number.length()-1]){
        case '1':
            if (Number.length() > 1){
                Text = (Number[Number.length()-2]=='1')?"рублей":"рубль";}
            else{Text = "рубль";}
            break;
        case '2':
        case '3': 
        case '4':
            if (Number.length() > 1){
                Text = (Number[Number.length()-2]=='1')?"рублей":"рубля";}
            else{Text = "рубля";}
            break;
        default :
            Text = "рублей";
            break;
    }
    std::cout << Number << " " << Text << std::endl;
}
std::string itos(long long number){
    std::string result;
    if (number < 0) {
        result = "-";
        number = number - number*2;
    }
    else{result= "";}
    long long divider = 1;
    while((number/divider) >= 10){divider*=10;}
    for(long long i = 1; i <= divider; divider/=10){
        long long buf = number/divider;
        switch(buf){
            case 0:
                result.append("0");
                break;
            case 1:
                result.append("1");
                break;
            case 2:
                result.append("2");
                break;
            case 3:
                result.append("3");
                break;
            case 4:
                result.append("4");
                break;
            case 5:
                result.append("5");
                break;
            case 6:
                result.append("6");
                break;
            case 7:
                result.append("7");
                break;
            case 8:
                result.append("8");
                break;
            case 9:
                result.append("9");
                break;
        }
        number-= buf*divider;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Одиннадцать рубль - или все-таки рублей?

Comment: А, ну да. Значит расширить фильтр на значения в диапазоне 11-14 (с учётом того, что это может быть и 111 и 2312), и анализировать также предпоследний символ

Comment: @Iceman как именно расширить? Раз уж написали ответ, будьте добры описать его полностью :)

Comment: Обновил ответ... Конвертер int_to_string нужен? ;)

Comment: За что минусуют, не понятно... Работает же.

Comment: @Iceman за обработку чисел в строковом виде. например

Answer (score -2):

[Склонения слов на PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215279/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php/215284#215284)

Цитата:

```
function declOfNum($num, $titles) {
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

    return $num . " " . $titles[($num % 100 > 4 && $num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($num % 10, 5)]];
}

echo declOfNum(5, array('человек просит', 'человека просят', 'человек просят'));
```