# Как склонять слово «день» по числам?

Tags: java, дата

Есть значение разницы двух дат в днях.
Как сделать форматирование в таком виде:

1 день, 2 дня, 3 дня, 4 дня, 5 дней, 20 дней и т.д.?

То бишь что бы менялось слова `день` и `дня`.

Comment: Так это же пишется собственноручно в 5 строк кода, не?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin может быть. я знаю вариант, но хотел узнать может есть какие-то уже готовые проверенные

Comment: Вы ради одного этого метода хотите найти библиотеку? В Java вряд ли будет встроен метод для склонения русских слов.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin я не говорил библиотеку. просто функцию или принцип.

Comment: @Tsyklop принцип можете здесь подсмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664884/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-21-22-23-24-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5java

Comment: Или на хабре, вроде даже библиотека есть: https://habrahabr.ru/post/37579/

Comment: @defaultlocale оформи в форме ответа ссылку на стак.

Comment: Не, я это не проверял и отвечать за это не буду :) Если у тебя заработало, опубликуй код в ответе и зачти, наверняка кому-нибудь пригодится.

Comment: @defaultlocale ок

Answer (score 5):

Как подсказали [default locale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178556/default-locale):

```
public String getDayAddition(int num) {

    int preLastDigit = num % 100 / 10;

    if (preLastDigit == 1) {
        return "дней";
    }

    switch (num % 10) {
        case 1:
            return "день";
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return "дня";
        default:
            return "дней";
    }

}
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664884/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-21-22-23-24-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5java)

Comment: слово "Ruble" в названии функции не смущает?

Comment: @Igor как-то все равно. умный человек переименует.

Comment: "В третьем бочонке 24 огурца." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx8hAI0UxRg

Answer (score 0):

Написал универсальную склонялку для разных слов, конечно если добавляется слово, то нужно самому описывать три вида окончаний:

0 индекс массива - 1 кошка, 101 кошка

1 индекс массива - 2 кошки, 102 кошки

2 индекс массива - 5 кошек, 11 кошек, 26 кошек, 10011 кошек

Для этого прилагаю три класса: util, enum, test с обработкой двух слов: день и месяц

Утилита:

```
public class WordDeclensionUtil {

/**
 * Получить слово в склонении в зависимости от переданного числа, например, для WordDeclensionEnum.MONTH
 * 11 месяцEВ
 * 21 месяц
 */
public static String getWordInDeclension(WordDeclensionEnum wordType, int n) {
    // смотрим две последние цифры
    int result = n % 100;
    if (result >=10 && result <= 20) {
        // если окончание 11 - 20
        return wordType.getDeclensions()[2];
    }

    // смотрим одну последнюю цифру
    result = n % 10;
    if (result == 0 || result > 4) {
        return wordType.getDeclensions()[2];
    }
    if (result > 1) {
        return wordType.getDeclensions()[1];
    } if (result == 1) {
        return wordType.getDeclensions()[0];
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Перечисление:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum WordDeclensionEnum {
MONTH(new String[]{"месяц", "месяца", "месяцев"}),
DAY(new String[]{"день", "дня", "дней"}),
;

/**
 * Склонения в зависимо от переданного количества единиц сущности.
 * Минимальный размер: 3 склонения;
 * index
 * 0 - 1 кошка, 101 кошка
 * 1 - 2 кошки, 102 кошки
 * 2 - 5 кошек, 11 кошек, 26 кошек
 */
private String[] declensions;
}
```

Тест для проверки окончаний слов перед запуском проекта:

```
class WordDeclensionUtilTest {

@Test
void getWordInDeclension() {

    int countTestCases = 9;
    int[] count = {1, 2, 5, 10, 19, 1001, 1011, 10006, 202};

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TwoFieldDto<WordDeclensionEnum, String[]>[] words = new TwoFieldDto[]{
            new TwoFieldDto<>(WordDeclensionEnum.MONTH, new String[]{"месяц", "месяца", "месяцев", "месяцев", "месяцев", "месяц", "месяцев", "месяцев", "месяца"}),
            new TwoFieldDto<>(WordDeclensionEnum.DAY, new String[]{"день", "дня", "дней", "дней", "дней", "день", "дней", "дней", "дня"}),
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < countTestCases; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            String wordInDeclension = WordDeclensionUtil.getWordInDeclension(words[j].getKey(), count[i]);
            assertEquals(words[j].getValue()[i], wordInDeclension, String.format("declension not equal: i = %s, j=%s", i, j));
        }
    }
}
}
```