# редактирование строки

Tags: java, строки

Работаю с клиентскими данными.
Есть строка

```
У вас 1 неполученная награда за уровень!
```

Цифра 1 собственно есть клиентскими данными.
Но если пользователь введет

```
У вас 7 неполученная награда за уровень!
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы слово неполученная и наград автоматически подстраивалось под цифру. Результат

```
У вас 7 неполученных наград за уровень!
```

Помогите составить подобный алгоритм.

Comment: Последняя цифра 1 -ая, 2,3,4  -ые, 5-0 -ых

Comment: а в случае например с числом 11?

Comment: Очевидно, что вы не первый человек, решающий такую задачу, так что алгоритм уже давно составлен. Даже на этом сайте пару раз пробегал, осталось только пойти в поиск и найти его.

Comment: Вот здесь метод, который можно будет переделать под Вашу задачу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718378/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC