# Проверка IF на слово с разными склонениями

Tags: php

Подскажите, получаю запрос пользователя, например "Вывести 20 рублей"

Делаю проверку

```
if ($text == 'Вывести ' . $money . ' рублей') {

} else {

}
```

Как мне быть, если запрос будет про, например, 3 рубля, склонение будет другое и проверка не пройдет уже

Прошу подсказки, мозг уже болит

upd. Мне не нужно менять склонения у слов, мне нужно делать == проверку строки, в которой может быть слово с разными склонениями, а делать "if рубль", "if рубля", "if рублей" не вариант, т.к. будут еще сравнения с месяцами и т.д. т код будет огромным
Но при этом должно быть четкое вхождение ==

Потом будет, например, "январе" и "январь"

Заранее спасибо..

Comment: Вот одна из тем, где обсуждается подобный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215279/

Comment: Можно использовать поиск по маске

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Склонения слов на PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215279/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php)

Comment: Мне не нужно менять склонения у слов, мне нужно делать == проверку строки, в которой может быть слово с разными склонениями, а делать "if рубль", "if рубля", "if рублей" не вариант, т.к. будут еще сравнения с месяцами и т.д. т код будет огромным Но при этом должно быть четкое вхождение ==

Comment: @Capkissel вам НУЖНО делать склонение слов по определенной цифре.  Эта функция на пару строчек. Далее склеиваете и проверяете с тем, что было передано. Если вам НЕ НУЖНО делать склонение - удачи с IF'ами. Другого "простого" решения, наверное, нет.