# Пишем функцию перевода чисел в строки (33 -> Тридцать три) на php и js

Tags: php, javascript

Помогите написать функцию, которая получает число с типом (double), например 33.61, а возвращает строку "Тридцать три рубля 61 копейка". Число можно передать любое. Есть мысли как реализовать на PHP или Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно в чем проблема. Заполняете массив для единиц, единиц второго десятка, десятков, сотен. Для каждого разряда подставляете соответствующее текстовое представление.
Склонение копеек и рублей смотрим [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89458/php-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-1-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4-2-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82).

Comment: Проблема в том, что я ни разу не сталкивался с написанием подобных функций на PHP или JS.

Comment: с предложением выполнить работу за вас не сюда. берете и пишите.

Comment: @eprivalov1 позвольте узнать чем реализация на php кардинально отличается от реализации на любом другом процедурном языке ?

Comment: @eicto просто мсье удивительным образом умеет выделять микрокусочки из общего алгоритма, оформлять их в виде вопросов, потом видимо копипастить в проект и получать готовый код. но тут, внезапно, его замысел был раскрыт. пичаль.

Comment: вот хороший прожект менеджер пропадает... (ну может не отличный, но и такие редкость)

Comment: да, всем надо заниматься своим делом. и развиваться самостоятельно тоже надо. видно стремление, но вот не научиться, а сделать какую-то систему, самому при этом, приложив минимум усилий. следующий вопрос не заставил себя ждать, все слишком запущено.