# Склонение даты в виде предложения. Функция

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Существует способ вывода даты в виде предложения, но только на английском языке. Собственно, вот сам код:

```
function ago( $time )
{
    if ( empty( $time )) return "Today";

    // get ci instance
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $time = mysql_to_unix( $time );
    $now = $CI->db->query('SELECT NOW( ) as now')->row()->now;
    $now = mysql_to_unix( $now );

    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $difference = $now - $time;
    $tense = "ago";

    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if ($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    if ($difference==0) {
        return "Just Now";
    } else {
        return "$difference $periods[$j] ago";
    }
}
```

Ну, в результате должно быть: "1 секунду назад", "2 секунды назад", "5 секунд назад" или "1 час назад", "2 часа назад", "5 часов назад" и так далее. То есть должны соблюдаться правила склонения слов.

Comment: и проблема то в чем?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы return "$difference $periods[$j] ago";
возвращал в зависимости от времени:
1 секунда назад, 
5 минут назад, 
3 минуты назад,

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/89458/186083

Answer (score 1):

Функция склонения числительных в русском языке. Принимает число и массив слов для склонения.

`declOfNum(25, ['секунду', 'секунды', 'секунд'])`

```
/**
 * Функция склонения числительных в русском языке
 *
 * @param int    $number Число которое нужно просклонять
 * @param array  $titles Массив слов для склонения
 * @return string
 **/
function declOfNum($number, $titles)
{
    $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $number." ".$titles[ ($number%100 > 4 && $number %100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($number%10, 5)] ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут у вас две задачи. Первая -- выбрать правильную форму (окончание) существительного при числительном. Вы можете найти множество решений загуглив `php russian plural`. Классический однострочник выглядит приблизительно так:

```
echo $n%10==1&&$n%100!=11?'минута':($n%10>=2&&$n%10<=4&&($n%100<10||$n%100>=20)?'минуты':'минут');
```

Вторая задача выбрать подходящую единицу измерения в зависимости от давности. Для этого можно использовать ваш код, заменив second, minute и т.д. на русские. Обычно имеет смысл показывать давность до определённого предела и в какой-то момент начать показывать полную дату или сочетать давность и дату: **2 года назад, 10 февраля**. Обратите внимание, что форм относительных величин может быть больше: не **1 день назад**, а **вчера**, не **30 минут назад**, а **полчаса назад**. Сформулируйте правила, по которым хотите отображать давность и определите границы времени, кода они срабатывают.

Отдельно стоит сказать о секундах и **только что**. Иногда пользователь довольно долго не перезагружает страницу и даже через полчаса будет видеть всё те же **5 секунд назад**. Для этого обновляйте давности на клиенте или не используйте слишком уж точные значения.

P.S.
Ходить в базу за now довольно необычно. mysql_to_unix -- очень подозрительная функция, так как MySQL умеет возвращать дату как метку времени ([UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)).

Comment: вывеськодводнустрочкубезпробеловпишите? удобночитать?

Comment: @teran Отнюдь! Просто это однострочник -- некая конструкция, которую копипастят из проекта в проект :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function plural($n, $form1, $form2, $form3) {
    $n  = abs($n) % 100;
    $n1 = $n % 10;

    if ($n > 10 && $n < 20) return $form3;
    if ($n1 > 1 && $n1 < 5) return $form2;
    if ($n1 == 1) return $form1;

    return $form3; 
}  

function formatRubString( $n ){
    return plural($n, "рубль", "рубля", "рублей");
}

 formatRubString(1);// Рубль
 formatRubString(3);// Рубля
 formatRubString(5);// Рублей
```